# Rails caching forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, caching

i developed a project using Ruby on Rails and i having a huge problem after putting it on production environment.

All forms seems to being cached.

If i fill a whole form and send it to the server, the next time i access that form to create a new object, all fields will be already filled with previous data. This only happens on production environment, and i found that when i set this line to false, everything works fine:

config.cache_classes = true

Seems that this cache_Classes is causing the problem but i think that maybe another thing is causing the problem because cache_classes would only cache classes and not forms and i think that i may have a great performance loss with this config setted to false.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show us the controller from which this form eventually renders? It sounds like you have page-caching on that page for some reason. Turning off `config.cache_classes` will solve the problem, but will come at a fairly major performance penalty.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/66f6b71c9bcf1d096d0f

This happens in any form, including this one. Could this be an issue from CanCan?

Comment: Nothing likely in there. How about the code for the view?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/5f3eed71b2341f359663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. In some models i was using cattr_accessor and i find that everything in forms that was being cached was the same fields i used cattr_accessor. Classes would be cached so seems that cattr_accessor would be cached too. I just replaced it with attr_accessor and everything works fine.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your browser's auto form completion feature.

Comment: I didnt help. I dont think is a browser or even a client-side related problem.

Comment: Ok. I hadn't seen this behavior in a Rails app before and thought it was worth looking at the browser layer.